# How to package JavaFx application

Tags: javafx-2

I use Eclipse and efxclipse plugin. I made a very simple JavaFx application following oracle documentation. My jdk version is jdk1.7-045. I notice that export application as a normal jar is different from normal Java application. What about if I want to make a normal jar file, and could be executed by double click jar file? Any hints.

```
D:\temp>java -classpath ./jfxrt.jar -jar Fxhello.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Ap
plication
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

-classpath and -jar can not be used together

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the classpath in the MANIFEST.MF of your jar file. The MANIFEST.MF will look like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: jfxrt.jar
```

Then, you can run your application as

```
java -jar Fxhello.jar
```